# change background in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

i am using fabric 1.4 and i have a problem when i want to change the background. the issue is as follow. i upload a image then press a button and load this image as background image in fabric canvas. when i go back to the previous page i clear the canvas with canvas.clear().renderAll(); and change the image i have chosen before. when i then load the image as background image on the canvas i can see the new image but if i click or touch the canvas it changes back to the previous one. i have no idea why this happens. can anyone help out? would be very much appreciate as i need it very soon for a drawing project.

thank you very much

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle test?!

Comment: it is hard to make a fiddle test as it is over more pages. if i do it all on one page and change on button click it works - did it actually with fiddle. but i think i depends on the different pages and the scopes. maybe a code snippet would help?

Comment: Maybe - let's see. :)

Comment: well... let me explain a bit more to it. i work with phonegap and ionic. i open a modal and have a form included there. in that form i can choose a image. when i then click a button i open another modal where i load the image in the fabric canvas. this works all fine. when i then decide to choose another image i want to paint on... i go back choose another image and click again the button i open the modal with the fabric canvas and the new image. and one click changes the bg image back. so how should i show you now the code for that. :) mmmmh...

Comment: would it be helpful if i would send you via mail the code snippets?

Comment: it seems i have it. :) canvas.dispose() does the trick. i don't know if there are any side effects but so far it seems its works

Comment: ok but after disposing the canvas i can't draw anymore. :(

Comment: ohhh that would be perfect. maybe it helps out. very much appreciated. would you like to send me your emailaddress

Comment: stefankienzle.de[at]gmail.com